# 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in Android Studio

Tags: android, vue.js, android-studio, cordova, quasar-framework

Has anyone encountered this error in Windows? using Quasar Cordova Android.

[image]

upon checking for the requirements using "cordova requirements"

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-32,android-30
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle\bin\gradle.BAT
```

It's completed. However whenever I run "quasar dev -m android". It is giving me the error (see screenshot from the cmd of vs code.) I can't find any solution of this on the internet. I'm using Quasar framework of Vue js.

and upon running a specific android using "quasar dev -m cordova -T android --e ["nameOfTheAVDMAnagerYouCreated"]"

[image]

I get this error in the cmd of cordova.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just build with Linux, which knows about `sh`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler what do you mean by that? I'm using windows.

Comment: `sh` stands for bash, the default command line language for UNIX systems. is it possible that someone set up the project on a mac, then committed parts of the project, e.g. environment configuration, that were not supposed to be committed?

Comment: no, I haven't set up my windows to any mac configuration. Is there a way to reset the settings to it? I think this is the only option left.

Answer (score 1):

Installing command-line tools from Android Studio solves this problem.

Start Android Studio
Click Tools->SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Check Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)
Press Ok to download it.

Comment: I needed to uninstall the old cmd line tools and install the latest set to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Weird error I got as well

Try simply restarting your computer. Worked for me

Comment: It still didn't work. Are you using windows and Quasar Framework?

Comment: I'm using Cordova (w/o Quasar) on windows. Does the error persist when creating a new project?

Comment: no but it does persist when you run the cordova in quasar connected to your android device.

Comment: Also have this issue, when running on windows, with Framework7 Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Open [issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1027)

This is also a common error with cordova. As Quasar is related to cordova or capacitor, I will share the solution here

**Open and run any android emulator first. Then run the script to initialize your hybrid application**